# Need help recalling a website that plays classical music with scrolling scores

Tags: sheet-music, classical-music

I last visited the site maybe 10 years ago. The site had only a handful of pieces. The one I remembered was Queen of the Night aria from the Magic Flute. The website would play the music with scrolling orchestral scores. You could click on a place in the sheet music and it would play from there. It was not midi but actual recordings. I would like to visit the site again, but I'm completely blanking on what the site is called. Hope someone here can help me recall the name of the site.